# Load C++ assembly (exe) from a C# application

Tags: c#

I'm trying to download a C++ assembly from an FTP server and load it from memory. I tried this by actually downloading the file from the server and including it as a resource, but the same result.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.SomeAssembly);
```

Pretty standard. I'm thinking it happens because it's a C++ assembly. I'm getting an exception:

> "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format"

I tried loading a C# assembly and it was fine, any ideas how I could load a C++ assembly? I saw posts on how to load DLL's, but not exe's.

Comment: Is it a C++/CLI assembly (i.e. managed C++) or a plain old C++ application?

Comment: It's not a C++/CLI assembly.

Comment: Then I'm not sure it's possible at all. Exe files might not have symbol definitions so it would be impossible to call any functions.

Comment: Well guess I'll have to port my stuff to C++ then. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why do you want to load this .exe

Comment: If it's C++ dll then you can use pinvoke and call the functions you want.

Comment: If you want to just execute the native exe then it's possible too. If you want to load it however into the same process it's a bit different story. You have to rebuild imports etc. I'm not sure if it's possible from C# though as it's quite hackish.

Comment: Even from C++, you probably can't invoke functions in an .exe file unless their addresses are fixes and known, but that would still be quite a hack.